# Slices along arbitrary axis

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array `A` such that

```
A.shape[axis] = n+1.
```

Now I want to construct two slices `B` and `C` of `A` by selecting the indices `0, .., n-1` and `1, ..., n` respectively along the axis `axis`. Thus

```
B.shape[axis] = C.shape[axis] = n
```

and `B` and `C` have the same size as `A` along the other axes. There must be no copying of data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# exemple data
A = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4, 5)
axis = 2
n = A.ndim
# building n-dimensional slice
s = [slice(None), ] * n
s[axis] = slice(0, n - 1)
B = A[s]
s[axis] = slice(1, n)
C = A[s]
```

One-liners :

```
B = A[[slice(None) if i != axis else slice(0, n-1) for i in xrange(n)]]
C = A[[slice(None) if i != axis else slice(1, n) for i in xrange(n)]]
```